# Could you tell me how to install mCrypt extension in php 8.0.26 ? I am using WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp, mcrypt, opencart-3

I am installing a theme in opencart. When I am trying to install it. It's showing error mCrypt extension is not installed. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASTuP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmZD5.png)

I have download the mCrypt extension for php 8.0.26. mCrypt version is 1.0.4. It's a complete package. I don't know how I have to install it. Could tell me how I can install it.

Comment: Since you are using WAMP (so windows) you need to find the PHP directory (the one that contains the php.ini file) and put the mcrypt.dll in the extensions folder where all the other DLLs are located. Once you do that you can add the `extension=mcrypt.dll` line in your PHP.ini. Not sure of the exact paths or filenames but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The mCrypt extension is no longer supported in PHP 7.2 and later versions, which is why you are seeing the error when trying to install the theme in OpenCart. Instead, you can use OpenSSL, which is the recommended encryption library for PHP.

To install OpenSSL, you can follow these steps:

Check if OpenSSL is already installed on your server by running the following command in the terminal: php -m | grep openssl. If it is already installed, you should see "openssl" listed.

If OpenSSL is not installed, you can install it by running the following command in the terminal: sudo apt-get install openssl.

Once OpenSSL is installed, you will need to enable it in your PHP configuration file. To do this, locate the php.ini file on your server (usually located in /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini or a similar location) and open it in a text editor.

Search for the following line: ;extension=openssl. Uncomment this line by removing the semicolon at the beginning, so that it reads: extension=openssl.

Save the changes to the php.ini file and restart the Apache server by running the following command in the terminal: sudo service apache2 restart.

After following these steps, you should be able to install the theme in OpenCart without seeing the mCrypt extension error.